# PigLatin - insert data into existing partition?

Tags: apache-pig, hcatalog

I have a file `test_file_1.txt` containing:

```
20140101,value1
20140102,value2
```

and file `test_file_2.txt` containing:

```
20140103,value3
20140104,value4
```

In HCatalog there is a table:

```
create table stage.partition_pk (value string)
Partitioned by(date string)
stored as orc;
```

These two scripts work nicely:

Script 1:

```
LoadFile = LOAD 'test_file_2.txt' using PigStorage(',') AS (date : chararray, wartosc : chararray);
store LoadFile into 'stage.partition_pk' using org.apache.hcatalog.pig.HCatStorer();
```

Script 2:

```
LoadFile = LOAD 'test_file_2.txt' using PigStorage(',') 
AS (date : chararray, wartosc : chararray);
store LoadFile into 'stage.partition_pk' using org.apache.hcatalog.pig.HCatStorer();
```

Table `partition_pk` contains four partitions - everything is as expected.

But lets say, there is another file containing data that should be inserterd in one of existing partitions. 
Pig is unable to write into partition that contain data (or I missed something?)
How do you manage loading into existing partitions (on not empty nonpartitioned tables)?
Do you read partition, union it with new data, delete partition (how?) and insert it as new partition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coming from HCatalog's site, https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HCatalog+UsingHCat, it says: " Once a partition is created records cannot be added to it, removed from it, or updated in it.". So, by the nature of HCatalog, you can't add data to an existing partition that already has data in it.

There are bugs around this that they are working on. Some of the bugs were fixed in Hive 0.13:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-6405 (Still unresolved) - The bug used to track the other bugs
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-6406 (Resolved in 0.13) - separate table property for mutable
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-6476 (Still unresolved) - Specific to dynamic partitioning
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-6475 (Resolved in 0.13) - Specific to static partitioning
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-6465 (Still unresolved) - Adds DDL support to HCatalog
Basically, it looks like if you don't want to use dynamic partitioning, then 0.13 might work for you . You just need to remember to set the appropriate property

What I've found that works for me is to create another partition key that I call build_num. I then pass the value of this parameter via the command line and set it in the store statement. Like so:

create table stage.partition_pk (value string)
Partitioned by(date string,build_num string)
stored as orc;

STORE LoadFile into 'partition_pk' using org.apache.hcatalog.pig.HCatStorer('build_num=${build_num}';

Just don't include the build_num partition in your queries. I generally set the build_num to a timestamp when I ran the job;

Comment: Thans for your answer. You've written: _Basically, it looks like if you don't want to use dynamic partitioning, then 0.13 might work for you . You just need to remember to set the appropriate propert_. Which parameter do you mean? And which bug solves my issue? Thanks

Comment: I updated my answer to include a work-around that works for me.

Comment: Thanks for you hin with additional partition. Have you checked what ifsan influance of this partition qhile quering the table? Isn't it swoing down the respose time?

Comment: Things start to slow down at around 10k partitions. Then you'll need to start tuning your metastore. I haven't seen any slowdowns due to more than one partition for a table. If you're going to update this table every few minutes, then this isn't going to be the right solution for you.

Comment: Btw, I have a separate process that runs once or twice a day. It grabs all of the data for a given date and all build_nums and inserts the data into a new build_num. it then removes the build_num partitions for that day that are lesser than the new partition. This keeps the number of files down and the total number of partitions down as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try using multiple partitions:

```
create table stage.partition_pk (value string) Partitioned by(date string, counter string) stored as orc;
```

Storing look like this:

```
LoadFile = LOAD 'test_file_2.txt' using PigStorage(',') AS (date : chararray, wartosc : chararray);
store LoadFile into 'stage.partition_pk' using org.apache.hcatalog.pig.HCatStorer('date=20161120, counter=0');
```

So now you can store data into the same date partition again by increasing the counter.